# How to download an application Java Card Connected Edition to a Omni Ring?

Tags: netbeans-8, javacard

I want to make a **Java Card Connected Edition Application** in a Omni Ring, based on **WEB (HTTP)**.

This **Contactless Ring** comes with **Java Card 3.0.1** and I already have an **ACR122U** reader/writer.

I downloaded **NetBeans IDE 8.2 RC** and made an example of the **Java Card Connected Edition (HTTP)** and everything worked correctly on the **NetBeans Virtual Card**, however I am not finding any information on how I download it to the Ring.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. The SLE78 only has 8 KiB of RAM available. That's not enough to run the Java Card Connected operating system. Actually, you will find preciously few implementations of Java Card Connected due to the high RAM requirements, which prohibits the use of cheap silicon. The few implementations (or rather, implementation) that I'm aware of used a contact based chip. Your chip runs the Java Card Classic variant.

That said, it is certainly possible to create a web server within an Applet (and this has been done in the past). Implementing TLS is going to be a lot trickier though, just because of the code size. TLS has many options. Instead you could tunnel the connection on a more smart card specific secure channel I suppose.